# How to display html output from xml file using xslt depending on dropdown selected items

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, dropdown

I have an external html file and external javascript file, i populated 2 dropdown-list in javascript file from xml. Now what I want to do is to use `xslt` to transform xml file to html depending on dropdown-lists selections. So I want to display xml files to html which matches with dropdown-lists items.

So when I select **2020** in the first dropdown and **January** in the second dropdown I want to use `xslt` to transform only xml elements under date which year is **2020** and month is **January**. Can anyone help me please, I have been looking for a solution for some days and I cant find the solution. I don't want to use xsltprocessor.setparameter plz find me another solution.

Here is my XML FILE:

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <date>
      <year>2020</year>
      <month>January</month>
      <day>11</day>
   </date>
   <date>
      <year>2021</year>
      <month>February</month>
      <day>14</day>
   </date>
   <date>
      <year>2023</year>
      <month>May</month>
      <day>19</day>
   </date>
   <date>
      <year>2029</year>
      <month>April</month>
      <day>31</day>
   </date>
</root>
```

Comment: You misunderstand XSL.  It does not responds to client events.  What you could do is; in the XSL file have something like `<xsl:if test="year = #VALUE#">...</xsl:if>` with a place holder (here #VALUE#).  You then put a javascript event handler on the select tag that will control the transformation.  This handler will each time replace the placeholder value in the XSL file and mixit with the XML file using a XSLTProcessor object and then replace the Dom elements.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but can you please give me an example because I am new to xslt. I will appreciate it so much.

Comment: I dont know how to connection #VALUE# with the value from external javascript. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT, logically, has 2 inputs: (a) the XML file, and (b) the values in the dropdown lists. The way you write XSLT with multiple inputs is to use stylesheet parameters.

You say "I don't want to use xsltprocessor.setparameter "

That's a bit like asking us how to tighten a nut and saying (without explanation) that you don't want to use a spanner. How else to you expect the XSLT to know the values in the dropdown lists without passing in a parameter?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. So I am asking again, is there another way to do what i asked before directly on xslt file, so without using parameters? If yes please give me an example. I will appreciate it so much.

Comment: Yes, there are ways of tightening a nut without using a spanner. But I wouldn't recommend them to anyone unless they can give me a darn good reason for not using a spanner.

Comment: I just have a project at school and the teacher said can you find another way. Thats why I want another solutions